# Drop user schema in oracle

Tags: oracle11g, schema

Anyone help me
i want to drop all user objects of a given user, i tried this query

```
    begin
   for i in (select 'drop '||object_type||' '|| object_name || ';' as sql_text from dba_objects where object_type in ('VIEW','PACKAGE','SEQUENCE', 'PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION', 'INDEX') and owner in ('SAMEH') )
     loop
       execute immediate i.sql_text;
     end loop;
end;
```

but i have this error:

```
ORA-06512: à ligne 4
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.
*Action:
```

Comment: Do you have objects that were created with quoted identifiers? If you query the object names do you have any that don't start with allowed characters?

Comment: i ran this query
select object_name from all_objects where owner ='SAMEH';
i dont have an object name with quoted identifiers

Comment: Not quotes in the object name as it's listed by that query; but names which start with a number, or some other invalid character, which would have had to be created with the name quoted. Or any mixed-case names, though those will get a different error. You can also use `dbms_output.put_line` to display the drop statement, which would identify which one(s) it's tripping up on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just have objects that were [created with quoted identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129) because they would have been invalid without them.

You can quote the names in the drop statement too, which would also handle any created with quoted mixed-case names:

```
begin
   for i in (select 'drop '||object_type||' "'|| object_name || '";'
       as sql_text from dba_objects
       where object_type in ('VIEW','PACKAGE','SEQUENCE', 'PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION', 'INDEX')
       and owner in ('SAMEH') )
     loop
       execute immediate i.sql_text;
     end loop;
end;
```

If you're running this as SAMEH then you could query `user_objects` instead. If you're running as a different user (with high privileges) you should include the schema name in the drop statements too:

```
   for i in (select 'drop '||object_type||' '||owner||."'|| object_name || '";'
```

You can optionally quote the schema name too.